# Bootstrap grid - missing Margin in Phone-mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, gutter

Hi i'm using twitter bootstrap's grid+responsive.

every thing is ok. When i reduce my browsers width to phone mode, the spans arrange vertical, which is ok. But there is no space between them now, i would expect them to get a margin-top or bottom of GutterWidth.

Any ideas how i can archieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [**media query**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)..

For example,

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div[class*="span"] {
      margin-bottom:2px;
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/60561)